# Error using jQuery Collision

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, collision-detection, collision

I'm still learning jQuery, and am having the hardest time with [eruciform's jquery-collision plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/) ([documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jquerycollision/)).

All I need is to get the names of the divs my draggables are overlapping on mouseup, but instead it only seems to want to return the code of the function itself as text.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyzhor/cumFL/11/). What am I doing wrong?

**Markup:**

```
<div id="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">
    <div class="topNav" id="topNav">
        <div class="dragElements">
            <div class="draggable" id="drag01">One</div>
            <div class="draggable" id="drag02">Two</div>
            <div class="draggable" id="drag03">Three</div>
            <div class="draggable" id="drag04">Four</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropElements">
            <div class="venn" id="venn1">
                <p/>&nbsp;<p/>Blue:
            </div>
            <div class="venn" id="venn2">
            <p/>&nbsp;<p/>Orange:
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Styles:**

```
.dragElements{
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
}
.dropElements{
    width: 100%;
    height: 275px;
}
#venn1{
    width:275px;
    height:275px;
    background-color:#0066FF;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#venn2{
    width:275px;
    height:275px;
    background-color:#FC0;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.draggable{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#66CCFF;
    cursor:pointer;  
    z-index:100;    
}
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.draggable").draggable();
    $("div.draggable").mousedown(function() {
        dragID = this.id
    });
    $("div.draggable").mouseup(function() {
        var colliders_selector = ".draggable";
        var obstacles_selector = ".venn";
        var hits = $(colliders_selector).collision(obstacles_selector, {
            mode: "collision"
        });
        alert(hits.text);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not invoking the function.

Change `alert(hits.text);` to `alert(hits.text());`

Comment: I just knew it'd be something simple like that. Thanks AlienWebguy!
So then I can get the id of the overlapping div with hits.attr("id")?
Great!  Thanks so much!